# Can not access sub directories without '\' (backward slash) in C#

Tags: c#, path, drive, getdirectories

I had a bizarre situation when try to access the sub directories of my c: drive:

first I tried the following code, the output was 0 (zero):

`MessageBox.Show(new DirectoryInfo("c:").GetDirectories().Length.ToString());`

but when add '\' to path (c:), it showed the exact number of sub folders in c: drive.

`MessageBox.Show(new DirectoryInfo("c:\\").GetDirectories().Length.ToString());`

but tried a another drive (d:) like:

`MessageBox.Show(new DirectoryInfo("d:").GetDirectories().Length.ToString());`

it retrieves all the sub direcotories.

can anyone explain why is that happened?

---

Well thanks guys. Now I got the point just **"c:"** returns current directory not root **"c:\"**. But I don't get any errors as  bemused mentioned.

Comment: I hope you are escaping the `\\` in the second example.

Comment: When you use just C: you'll actually get the default directory for that drive.  Which is fairly random.

Answer (score 5):

`\` is an escape character.
`\"` inserts a `"` character in a string, without terminating the string literal (eg, `"I have a \"quoted\" word!"`)

Use a literal string: `@"C:\"`; these literals ignore escape characters.

---

The path `C:` without a `\` refers to the current directory within the `C` drive, which is not necessarily `C:\` ([each drive has its own current directory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/11/10073890.aspx)).

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that it is interpreting "c:" as the current environment folder on the c: drive, which has no subfolders.  But when you specify a different drive than the one it's executing on ("d:"), it defaults to the root of that drive.

It should be easy enough check - compare the full path of DirectoryInfo("c:") and DirectoryInfo("c:\")

```
Console.WriteLine(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"c:").FullName);

>> c:\project\test\bin\debug

Console.WriteLine(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"c:\").FullName);

>> c:\
```